# Plotting multiple patches from list of patches matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple centered circle sets on a single figure. I have a function for creating patches of circles. I use this to create a list of total patches. However when I try to add these to my figure I can only see the last set of circles.

This is the current outcome:

[image: This is the outcome]

Something like this is the desired outcome:

[image: Something like this is the desired outcome]

This is my code:

"""

```
def add_circles(center, radius_gt, area_pred, area_db):
    # fig, ax = plt.subplots()#figsize = (10,10)) # note we must use plt.subplots, not plt.subplot

    circle = plt.Circle(center, (radius_gt/2), facecolor='None', alpha=1, linewidth=1.5, linestyle='--', edgecolor='g')
    circle_pred = plt.Circle(center, gen_diameter(area_pred)/2, color='blue')
    circle_db = plt.Circle(center, gen_diameter(area_db)/2, color='r')
    
    patches = [circle_db, circle_pred, circle]
            
    return center, patches

total_patches = []

center = [5,0]
center, patches = add_circles(center, 3, average_3_pred, average_3_db)
[total_patches.append(patch) for patch in patches]
print(center)
# [ax.add_patch(patch) for patch in patches]

center[0] = center[0] + (5 + gen_diameter(average_3_db)/2 + gen_diameter(average_4_db)/2)
center, patches = add_circles(center, 4, average_4_pred, average_4_db)
[total_patches.append(patch) for patch in patches]
print(center)
# [ax.add_patch(patch) for patch in patches]

center[0] = center[0] + (5 + gen_diameter(average_4_db)/2 + gen_diameter(average_6_db)/2)
center, patches = add_circles(center, 6, average_6_pred, average_6_db)
[total_patches.append(patch) for patch in patches]
print(center)
# [ax.add_patch(patch) for patch in patches]

center[0] = center[0] + (5 + gen_diameter(average_6_db)/2 + gen_diameter(average_7_db)/2)
center, patches = add_circles(center, 7, average_7_pred, average_7_db)
[total_patches.append(patch) for patch in patches]
print(center)
# [ax.add_patch(patch) for patch in patches]

center[0] = center[0] + (5 + gen_diameter(average_7_db)/2 + gen_diameter(average_9_db)/2)
center, patches = add_circles(center, 9, average_9_pred, average_9_db)
[total_patches.append(patch) for patch in patches]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()#figsize = (10,10)) # note we must use plt.subplots, not plt.subplot

[ax.add_patch(patch) for patch in total_patches]

ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(0,80)
ax.set_ylim(-10,10)
```

"""

---

---

Comment: It works for me...I had to change some stuff 'cause this isn't a MCVE, but nothing critical. 
So there's no way to debug without a proper MCVE...

Comment: Especially as it may be that the problem is with the values of the center circles or something, which cannot be determined without the various (missing) parameter values in your code.